# java code not working for while loop

Tags: java

i am trying to execute a code for 5 minutes within while loop.

```
long init= System.currentTimeMillis();
while(((System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000%60)<5){

//some part of code
}
```

but i am not able to get it working any suggestions how to fix it.

Comment: try to use Timer see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: what the `time` variable indicates ?

Comment: long init= System.currentTimeMillis(); while(((System.currentTimeMillis()-init)/1000%60)<5){

Comment: if u change time to init it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` depends on the implementation and on the Operating system.

Instead use the `System.nanoTime()` which returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.

That might be causing you time problems .

```
long init= System.nanoTime();
while(((System.nanoTime()-init)/1000000000/60)<5){

//some part of code
}
```

Comment: how to achieve it through System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Answer (score 0):

**Just:** Change the code as below and try again:

```
while(((System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000%60)<5){
```

To

```
while(((System.currentTimeMillis()-init)/1000/60)<5){
```

change `time` to `init` and `%` to `/`